# Calling a procedure in a different aspx page (within the same project)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, subroutine

In my asp.net project, I have two particular aspx pages (lets say PageA.aspx and PageB.aspx)

In the codebehind PageA.aspx.vb, I want to call "Sub GetDefaultValues()" which happens to be in PageB.aspx

**Update:**
PageB.aspx has textbox controls that contain default values (which are being read in Sub GetDefaultValues). Those default values get populated into the textboxes of PageA.aspx (based on certain conditions)

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a separate class that holds the method and call it from both pages.

Comment: From a class, how do I read from the controls of PageB.aspx and write to PageA.aspx ?

Comment: I just read your update and what you are trying to do can't be done.  A web browser makes the requests to the server.  What you are proposing is for the server to make a request to the browser to get the input in a textbox on some page that has already been served.  Perhaps if you had some JQuery hitting a web service with the values and pageA constantly hitting a different web method you could work something out, but it would be a lot of effort and some might say a hack.

Comment: Well, is the method you want to call GetDefaultValues()? If so cant you handle the default values from the class? If that is the case, then read those values via attributes or methods with the code behind on PageA.aspx and PageB.aspx.

Comment: The default values could change, depending on customer's selection on PageA